# Android: attributes mParam1 and mParam2 when generating a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have just created a new fragment and I have realized there are two attributes called `mParam1` and `mParam2`. What these attributes mean? what are they for? why 2 and not 1 or 3?

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: They are just parameters to be passed to the fragment and they can be any number based on your scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these Parameters to pass a message or any value from the activity to the fragment. eg. when use instantiate the fragment `new BlankFragment("message 1", "Message 2");`.

You can have any number of parameters, however, by default Android Studio provides you two.